# Janus GridEX BackSpace doesn't raise InitCustomEdit

Tags: c#, gridex

I have to use a text box as a custom control editor for `FilterRow` of a `Janus GridEX` so that I can handle its `TextChanged` event and do some asynchronous stuff while maintaining the focus on the current cell. 
Here's the code :

```
gridEX1.RootTable.Columns.Cast<GridEXColumn>().Where(x=>x.Visible).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.EditType=EditType.Custom);
            gridEX1.InitCustomEdit += GridEX1_InitCustomEdit;
            gridEX1.EndCustomEdit += GridEX1_EndCustomEdit;
```

and

```
private void GridEX1_InitCustomEdit(object sender, InitCustomEditEventArgs e)
        {
            txt.TextChanged -= TxtOnTextChanged;
            txt.Text = e.Value?.ToString()+e.EditChar;
            e.EditControl = txt;
            txt.TextChanged += TxtOnTextChanged;
        }

        private void GridEX1_EndCustomEdit(object sender, EndCustomEditEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = txt.Text;
        }
```

Everything is working fine except that hitting `BackSapce` on filter row doesn't put the cell in edit mode ( `InitCustomEdit` does not fire)

Any idea how should I solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried ovveriding IsInputKey/Char ?

Comment: No. How should I do that ? where I have to override it?

Comment: Derive a class from GridEx and then override that method.

Comment: You can try handle the backspace key in the keypressed event and put the control in editmode

Comment: @Sievajet the problem is that whenever I run `gridEx.FilterRow.BeginEdit()` I get an error that says only rows that represent a real record can be edited.

Comment: Try setting the gridEX or current gridEXColumn EditMode